# ionic 4 problem when adding content before ion-virtual-scroll

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this code and it's working totally fine using ionic 4 and angular 8

```
<ion-content>
<ion-virtual-scroll>
...
...
...
</ion-virtual-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

after added some content before `ion-virtual-scroll` it cost to this problem.
the items not showing in the right time [see Gif]

```
<ion-content>
<div class="content-header">...</div>
<ion-virtual-scroll>
...
...
...
</ion-virtual-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

[image]

when I `display:none` the class `.content-header` it work fine again.

**Q:**

**is there a way to make ion-virtual-scroll load more content on the screen?**

**is there a way to hide the .content-header after scrolling down (may it work)?**

Comment: Did you use margin for header? If so, put same margin for vitualscroll=> margin-botto:-margin you set from div header

Comment: Or if not share you css of header you added

Comment: yep it has a margin-bottom: 6em; I will try your answer

Comment: Oppa, It's solved, but without any margin, just organized the div on the page, I will add the screens down

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote the question I was not thinking that some div without any CSS will make this issue, but it does.

this screenshot with the problem 
[image]

after changing the to this order the `<ion-virtual-scroll>` detect the hight correctly. 
[image].

I hope it's clear. it's was only deleted a  `<div class="ion-padding">`

[image]